# RegEx to match capitalized words with a single space between them

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a RegEx that would match the following:

```
"United States"     // match
"United   States"   // not match
"united States"     // not match
"United states"     // not match
"  United States"   // not match
"United States   "  // not match
```

e.g it will require every word to start with a capital letter and have only a single space between words. It also must deny any trailing or leading whitespace charcaters.

Thanks

Comment: Are capital letters allowed in the middle of a word?

Comment: @Luke You edit was approved, but it was a bad edit. The tags are not unrelated, since regex implementations can differ from one to the next, so the underlying technology is potentially fundamental to providing a working answer.

Comment: Show your effort first..

Comment: @GrantThomas Oh, forgot about different engines, I should have let '.Net' tag, my bad

Comment: This is a rather trivial exercise. A few minutes on http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html would have you sorted out in short order. Specifically, [literals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) are what you are seeking.

Comment: @shakurov No, capital letters are not allowed in the middle of a word.

Comment: @mcl However, your example is a name, and a name can be quite literally _anything_ representable by characters, with middle-of-word capitals being fairly common, and bound to come up in place names; just an observation to maybe take note of, if you intend this to be scalable at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description is quite vague, but as a general case, `^[A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z][a-z]*)*$` should work without IgnoreCase flag.

Answer (score 0):

Like this: ?

`^[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*$`

Comment: But it doesn't account for more than 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

The following is similar to @dotNET's answer, but it accounts for non-ASCII character classes:

```
^[\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]\w*( [\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]\w*)*$
```

I've allowed mid-word non-lowercase characters here, because, in unicode, there're *a great deal* more character classes than just lowercase and uppercase.

To match words with strictly lowercase mid-letters,

```
^[\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]\p{Ll}*( [\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]\p{Ll}*)*$
```